# Setting a Font with outline Color in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, label, outline

I'm dynamically adding Labels to panels in my code.

Something I want to do is be able to outline the font so that it can stand out from the background color of the panel.

The problem is I don't know how to create a outline for my font or even a shadow effect in C# using Winforms.

Anyone know what I should look at or can point me in the right direction?
If you don't understand what I mean, the following picture is what I would like: (the Outer lining)

[image]

Comment: Is that winform? WPF? ASP.Net?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had specified. It's in Winform @GabrielGM

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you have to custom paint your own control. Here is an example for a `Label`. Note that it's just a demo, you should try finding out more on custom painting in winforms:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public CustomLabel()
    {
        OutlineForeColor = Color.Green;
        OutlineWidth = 2;
    }
    public Color OutlineForeColor { get; set; }
    public float OutlineWidth { get; set; }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), ClientRectangle);
        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        using (Pen outline = new Pen(OutlineForeColor, OutlineWidth)
            { LineJoin = LineJoin.Round})
        using(StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
        using(Brush foreBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
        {
            gp.AddString(Text, Font.FontFamily, (int)Font.Style,
                Font.Size, ClientRectangle, sf);                                
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.3f, 1.35f);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(outline, gp);                
            e.Graphics.FillPath(foreBrush, gp);                            
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the outline color via `OutlineForeColor` property, you can change the outline width via the `OutlineWidth` property. When you change these properties in the designer, the effect is not applied immediately (because there is not any code to do that, I want to keep it short and simple), the effect is applied only when the form is focused.

What you can add more is mapping the `TextAlign` to the `Alignment` of the `StringFormat` (named `sf` in the code), you can also override some event raising methods to add more control over the look and feel (such as to change the `ForeColor` when the mouse is over the label...). You can even create some shadow effect and glow effect (it requires a little much more code).

[image]

Comment: Will definitely have to work around my current solution. But that is my problem. Thanks alot @king-king.

Comment: I know this is about 7 years too late, but when I add ``sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;`` it isn't centred, it's off to the right slightly, I can't make sense of it as before applying this custom class the text was centred...

Comment: I found a full solution here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20464/A-Simple-Label-Control-with-Border-Effect