# How to outline stroke c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, contour, stroke, outline

We want to outlined font. But we can't give stroke(outline-contour).

Contour interior was correct. What should we do to the stroke to outside?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have this tagged as C#? Or would a front-end solution like this work?

```css
body {
       background-color: red;
     }

    .outlined {
        font-size: 75px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        color: white;
        text-shadow:
          -2px -2px 0 #000,  
           2px -2px 0 #000,
          -2px 2px 0 #000,
           2px 2px 0 #000;
        }
```

```html
<p class="outlined">Example</p>
```

Comment: windows form application @Tyler Roper

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842722/setting-a-font-with-outline-color-in-c-sharp